# which directory beanstalk uses to deploy my code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have .env in my code. I copy it to s3. I want to delete it from my GitHub and beanstalk download it when it starts. which directory I should use?
I see my code is on

```
/var/app/current/
/var/www/html/
,...
```

I want to use .ebextensions

```
commands:
  01_get_env_vars:
    command: aws s3 cp s3://test/.env DIRECTORY
```

does it have a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best way would be to use [container_commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands) instead of `commands`.

The reason is that  `conatiner_commands` run in the staging folder `/var/app/staging`:

> The specified commands run as the root user, and are processed in alphabetical order by name. Container commands are run from the **staging directory**, where your source code is extracted prior to being deployed to the application server.

Thus your code could be:

```
container_commands:
  01_get_env_vars:
    command: aws s3 cp s3://test/.env .
```

where `DIRECTORY` is replaced by `.`.